# Plot a curve that has different colors depending on a parameter

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to plot a curve with some measurement data. It is available as an array that contains items of the form `[t,b]`, where t is the parameter that I want to plot and `b` is a string that describes the status of the measurement equipment. I now want to plot the values of `t` and have the line colored depending on the value of `b`. My code so far is

```
import pylab as pl
measurements = [[0, "a"], [1, "b"], [2, "c"]]
times = pl.arange(0, 3, 1)
values = zip(*measurements)[0]
parameters = zip(*measurements)[1]
pl.plot(times, values)
pl.show()
```

The line should now have different colors, depending on the values in `parameters`. How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to do this is with matplotlib's `colormap` API.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as pl
from matplotlib import cm

pl.scatter(times, values, c = cm.spectral(1.*values/max(values)))
```

Obviously you'll want to use some other function to get a color from your data.  In general though, `cm.spectral` ([or any other `colormap`](http://www.scipy.org/Cookbook/Matplotlib/Show_colormaps?action=AttachFile&do=get&target=colormaps3.png)) will return a color given a float between zero and one, or an int between 0 and 255.

As a general comment, you might also be better off using numpy arrays rather than trying to `zip` your data together.  It might be easier with more complicated data structures than this example.

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as pl
from matplotlib import cm

measurements = np.array([[0, "a"], [1, "b"], [2, "c"]])
times = np.arange(3)
values = np.array(measurements[:,0], dtype=float)
parameters = np.array(measurements[:,1], dtype='S1')

pl.scatter(times, values, c = cm.spectral(values/max(values)))
pl.show()
```

Comment: Unfortunately that code does not work (and not only because of the missing bracket) and I also do not find a colormap tutorial that helps me in my case.

Comment: Sorry, should be `scatter` to allow for color to be a list of colors of the same shape.  See edit.

Answer (score -6):

The easiest way to draw a graph probably would be to use google's Chart API: https://developers.google.com/chart/

This isn't purely python at all, but a resource worth looking at. Hope it helps.

Comment: Hmm, no, that is unfortunately out of the question. I am bound to use pylab. And the whole thing is embedded into more Python code, so I really doubt that it is the easiest way to interface with Google Chart.